# Pi-4 with fans and ribbon cable

Tags: pi-4, cooling, cable, connectors

New to this. I bought a pi-4 kit. It has dual heatsink fans that get connected to pin 4 and 6. however, I want to do other projects and need to connect a ribbon cable to it. how can i do that while still having the fans connected?

Answer (score 0):

Take a ribbon cable, remove some 3 mm of the plastic coating of the wires leading to pin #4 and #6. Then, cut off the plug of the cable leading to the fan, separate the last 10 mm of this cable's wires, and remove the last 3 mm of the coating. Then, solder these two wires to the corresponding wires of the ribbon cable. Finally, secure the soldering joint you've just made with electrical tape.

Answer (score 0):

Consider other 5V and ground pins on the board, like pin 2 for 5V, pin 9 for ground.

If all the V+/ground pins are used up, you may try to extend the pins. There are multiple ways. One of the simplest way is to connect the pin to a breadboard, such that you will have a few extra holes to connect to the same pin.

Beware not to connect too many devices. You may overload the Pi.